# Odoo 10 : How to increase the field width?

Tags: css, xml, forms, field, odoo

I have a form view which looks like this :

[image]

the xml looks like this :

```
<notebook>
<page>
<group string="In case of student employee or intern">   
     <field name="immatriculation" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
     <field name="studentStatus" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
     <field name="studentQuestionnaire" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
     <field name="studentOtherjobs" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
</group>
</page>
</notebook>
```

I would like to increase the width of these fields so that All text (e.g. Confirmation of Student Status (Mandatory Internship) )
comes in a single line. I tried below but didnt see any changes in width :

```
<field name="studentStatus" attrs="{'readonly':True}" style="width:200px"/>
```

What is the right way to change the width of these fields inside a group?

Answer (score 4):

Just put a `<div/>` tag it will render 50% space for label and 50% for fields
Like this

```
<group string="In case of student employee or intern">
     <div /> <!-- here it is -->
     <field name="immatriculation" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
     <field name="studentStatus" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
     <field name="studentQuestionnaire" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
     <field name="studentOtherjobs" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
</group>
```

if you need space more then 50% then you have to apply style

Answer (score 1):

When the checkbox string is long, I'd put the string to the right of the box.

[image: Example]

You may consider below view.

```
<group>
    <label string="Confirmation" for="confirm1" class="oe_inline"/>
    <div>
        <field name="confirm1" nolabel="1" class="oe_inline" modifiers="{}"/>
        <label string="blah blah blah" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
    <label string=" " for="confirm2" class="oe_inline"/>
    <div>
        <field name="confirm2" nolabel="1" class="oe_inline" modifiers="{}"/>
        <label string="blah blah blah" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
    <label string=" " for="confirm3" class="oe_inline"/>
    <div>
        <field name="confirm3" nolabel="1" class="oe_inline" modifiers="{}"/>
        <label string="blah blah blah" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky but you could try a simple solution by setting colspan to use the whole width of the notebook page.

`<group string="In case of student employee or intern" colspan="4">`

Comment: Sorry! width didnt change. still the same!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ... maybe u have to do it on every field

```
<field name="field1" style="width:40%%" />
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You can put that in XML in the field you want to increase or decrease. The % depends on you.

Comment: That's obvious but you should put that as part of your answer and not a comment. I'm not sure you have explained why that answers the question.